# convert negative decimal number into HEX

Tags: excel, programming-languages, hex

I must admit I don't remember much about HEX and so on from school (25 years ago). In any case, I have some values in decimal format which I need to convert into HEX. I am using Excel but I could write a function in VBA if necessary (or do it by code in VB.NET).

I already know how the HEX-result should look like (another source) but I need to use Excel to get this result exactly. The source of decimal input and also the result of the (right) HEX result is from a Linux-system if that is important to know.

Positive numbers seem to be converted correctly while negative numbers give me an headache in the sense that Excel adds in the beinning of the HEX two additional letters (two FF) compared to result I want.

Example: 
Decimal input: -524288

Correct HEX-output I must obtain: FFF80000

Using formula in Excel I get: FFFFF80000
(I get 2 FF extra in the beginning of the HEX-output)

Another example:

Decimal Input: -29446758

should be FE3EAD9A

but in Excel I get FFFE3EAD9A

It seems like I always get 2 extra FF in the HEX-output.

Can someone explain (in an easy way) why I get the 2 extra FF and if I can safely remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Excel, `=DEC2HEX` by default returns 10 characters.

If you want to get just 8, as your question suggest use:

```
=DEC2HEX(A1,8)
```

Nevertheless, unless you have a compatibility issue, you may left the default numbers. Remember that the "F" char acts for negative numbers as a padding char (the same way "0" is for positive numbers).

**Edit**

The above fails for negatives, as you stated in your comment.

The following works:

```
=RIGHT(DEC2HEX(A1),8)
```

Comment: THx - The function =RIGHT(DEC2HEX(A1),8) semms to work perfectly. Thanks also for explaining =DEC2HEX always returns 10 characters and that the extra FF were simply padding char. This was the quickest solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are doing because you haven't included your formula. My guess is that you are using a function like this:

```
=DEC2HEX(A1)
```

Although it has an optional parameters to control how many digits are returned, that doesn't work when the input is negative.

Instead you should use some VBA:

```
Public Function DecToHex(val As Variant) As Variant

DecToHex = Hex(val)

End Function
```

Comment: David, in the debug window I enter a number and its negative and the results aren't the same number with a negative:
? Hex$(29446758)
1C15266
? Hex$(-29446758)
FE3EAD9A

Comment: @Doug It's the complement. For example `Hex(2)= 02` and `Hex(-2)= FE`

Comment: @Doug That's how it works. Hex$ returns the value when interpreted as an unsigned integer value.

Comment: Thx. Yes, I was using the function =DEC2HEX(A1). I tried your VBA-code but I get an DataType-error (Hex$ is getting highlighted in VBA-editor). But that is probably because I don't recall how to use VBA correctly.

Comment: @moster Not sure what that didn't work. Perhaps the edit with Hex instead of Hex$ does for you. In any case, belisarius's VBA free version will get the job done fine.